# SVG with size in px and percentage?

Tags: svg, snap.svg

I'm trying to create an SVG element with a width defined by a percentage of the parent and a fixed value, say 50% + 20px. For normal html elements, in the CSS you can use `calc(50% + 20px)`. Is there an equivalent way to do this for embedded SVGs? Specifically, I'm using snap.svg, though I'm not sure if this capability exists with SVGs in general.

EDIT:

Tried setting `<svg>` width with percentages and px, which I couldn't get to work. I tried both:

```
<svg width='calc(50% + 20px)'>...</svg>

<svg width='50% + 20px'>...</svg>
```

I also tried setting it in CSS:

```
svg {
  width: calc(50% + 20px);
}
```

Comment: You can do this for the root `<svg>` element. Have you tried it and found issues?

Comment: I was trying to do it for an element within the SVG - like a `<rect>`

Comment: No, that's not possible yet. It will be at some point in the future.

Comment: OK, good to know. If I have nested <svg> elements I could achieve a similar effect, though? (eg, set the <svg> width this way and make a <rect> inside with a 100% width)

Comment: I'm trying this with an SVG element and can't get it to work. :/

Comment: Add your markup to the question.

Comment: Added different ways I tried.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible with the upcoming SVG2 as `width` etc. become [geometry properties](https://css-tricks.com/svg-properties-and-css/) and then you can style them with `calc`